# Does the owner have access to my account in Gmail for business?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I'm an employee and my company is using Gmail (for business) for all communications.

Are they able to see and review all the email messages I send?

Comment: If your asking the question if your employer can change the password to their account, the answer is, of course they can.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually I'm asking how to permanently delete a message from my bussiness account

Comment: Depends on the settings of the business account.  Many businesses implement an email archive system, so every email you download, is also retained automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's actually one of the selling points: data ownership.

Really though, you shouldn't be using work email for personal business.

Comment: Does deletion from inbox and trash bin may help? What are other ways?

Comment: @bogert If you trash it, it's ok. But don't use the email compagny otherwise that professionally.

Comment: @MartialE that happened accidentally since I have 3 gmail accounts signed in. How do you know that trashing a message is enough?

Comment: @bogert - You don't because they could also have email retention setup.  The simple answer is don't log into your personal account while at work.

Comment: Ramhound is right. One of the reasons we went with corporate gmail was because sales people were trying to abscond with their client lists (delete the client stuff and leave) and with gmail we could recover it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as well as deleted emails. The component of Google Apps for Work (now known as GSuite) designed to explore employee emails and chats is called [Vault](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_us/products/vault/).

> Manage, retain, search and export your organization’s email and on-the-record chats.

Further, the key selling point is search in the org:

> Google-powered search to find content quickly. Find and retrieve valuable information, even from closed accounts. It’s a smart way to gather what your legal team needs and prevent data loss from employee turnover.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is delete it "forever" from within the Trash folder and hope for the best. We had Gmail for business for a short time before switching to Exchange, and I am pretty sure that all of the emails are available to the admins, even those in the trash folder. For the most part I have to assume that your Admins are not searching through the trash folders unless there is a good reason too, personally I couldn't be bothered.